# How would I echo a slide only if the json object contains an image?

Tags: php, json, loops

#### My Question:

How would I echo a slide only if the json object contains an image?

#### My Issue:

I'm not sure how I should treat a for loop of a json object to echo a slide only if it contains an image.

#### Objective:

I want to be able to echo a div only if there is an image in the json object, and then echo a link around the image so I can link to the story.

#### Additional:

How could I not echo a slide div inside "#slides" when there is no image?

Is there something in PHP that would let me echo the slide if it contains an image without breaking the foreach loop?

Or am I going to have to break the foreach loop,store the information for only the slides holding an image and re-loop through them? If so what would be the best way to do so?

I'm lost because if I make an if statement for $key=="img" its only going to echo the image portion, not sure how I should handle it.

### Code:

**NEWS.JSON**

```
{
    "1": {
        "id": "1",
        "img":"./images/newspost/07-05-12.jpg",
        "link":"http://www.cnn.com/2012/07/05/world/europe/france-air-crash-report/index.html",
        "title": "Example",
        "date":"02/08/12",
        "content": "Example"
    },
    "2": {
        "id": "2",
        "img":"",
        "link":"http://online.wsj.com/article/SB10001424052702304141204577508500189367804.html?mod=googlenews_wsj",
        "title": "Example",
        "date":"09/03/10",
        "content": "Example"
    }
}
```

**HOME.PHP**

```
/* Error Report on */
error_reporting(E_ALL);

/* Open Json file */
$json = file_get_contents("./content/news.json");

/* Setup iterator to go through file */
$jsonIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator(json_decode($json, TRUE)),RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

/* Create SLIDES for SLIDESHOW */
echo "<div id='slides'>";
```

At this point I DON'T want to echo anything if no image exists.

```
foreach($jsonIterator as $key => $val)
{

if(is_array($val))
{
echo "<div>";
}

if($key=="link")
{
echo "<a href='$val'>";
}

if($key=="img"&&$val!="")
{
echo "<img alt='' src='$val'></img>";

}



if(!is_array($val)&&$key=="content")
{
echo "</a>";
echo "</div>";
}

}
```

End loop/what needs to show only if image exists.

```
echo "</div>";
/* End SLIDES creation */
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I show you the way how I would do it:

```
$json = file_get_contents("./content/news.json");
$jsonArray = json_decode($json, true);

// Start slideshow...
echo "<div id='slideshow'>";

foreach ($jsonArray as $entry) {
  if ($entry['img'] == '') {
    continue; // Just don't do anything with this entry, go to next one
  }

  // News begins.
  echo "<div>";

  // For example:
  echo "<a href='" . $entry['link'] . "'>";
  // Etc.

  // News ends.
  echo "</div>";
}
```

I think it's much more simpler than your way.

Comment: I was using the recursive iterator iterator to allow for looping through deeper than one object for json, but I merged the two options, thanks.